# win7 headphone jack not working

Tags: windows-7, audio

I don't remember what happened, but I realized my asus laptop has no sound coming from the headphone jack when I'm on windows. I remember it working a month ago.

I have an Asus laptop with realtek audio hardware on windows-7(64). I get no sound from my headphone jack, and here are what I have done to try and fix it:

- uninstalled the driver and let windows install one
- installed the realtek HD-Audio-Codec on my own

It works fine on linux. But on windows;

- if the drivers are installed, then I get no sound with the headphones plugged in
- if the drivers are not installed, I have 2 speakers to choose from in the sound menu. Sound comes from one (laptop speakers) and sound doesn't come from the other (plugged-in headphones).

As a side-note,the mic is detected just fine when plugged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, how this works is beyond me

I went to the ASUS website and downloaded the audio driver for my computer. This didn't change anything, except make my laptop speakers sound better.

Now, when I reboot into windows from linux, the jack doesn't work. But when I turn the computer off and on, and boot into windows, the jack works.

There it is. A complete mystery. At least I know how to make it work, now.

Comment: Holy meow!! that's completely magical and works for me. Super weird. Do you know how to fix this permanently already?

Comment: @Phelios No mate, I havent looked into it since then. I just turn it off and on

Comment: Happens to me too on a HP laptop when rebooting from Linux to Windows 7. Suspending + waking up Windows works too. Didn't reinstall drivers