# Reinstalled Windows 7, sound won't play through headphone jack

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, headphones, headphone-jack

So I recently reinstalled Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit edition, and though my computer plays sound through the speakers, when I plug any earbuds or headphones into the headphone jack I can't hear anything.

I can see that audio is playing in the volume bar, but nothing is playing through the headphones. I've updated the drivers with ones from [here](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=X54L) and nothing changes. I have also tried the drivers direct from Realtek, they didn't work either.

Nothing is wrong with my headphones or the headphone jack themselves because I can boot into my Lubuntu partition and everything works perfectly fine.

I've seen [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/556206/win7-headphone-jack-not-working), and I tried following what they did, but it still didn't work.

Also, when I bring up the Sound window, it doesn't [show anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Rsp.png) other than the speakers even though I have it show disabled and disconnected devices.

Here are my relevant specs:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit edition
- Asus X54L BBK2 Laptop (which    uses an Asus K54L motherboard)

I've got no idea what to do now. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: try deleting any and all audio devices in your Devices' Control Panel. Your devices will all automatically reinstall when you either rescan or reboot.

Comment: Your Jack is busted. Same thing happened to me, figured it out yesterday. If your warranty's still going, get it fixed. I'm taking my HP Envy 14 Ultrabook back to Bestbuy so they can fix it.